# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Artificial Intelligence's [first moderator election](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: nbro] [image: John Doucette]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4701123745153024/0).

---

More hands ended up being needed, so the Community Team reached out to the top runner up in this election — let's welcome them to the team too:

[image: Dennis Soemers]

Answer (score 5):

I am really flattered by this opportunity and vote of confidence! I will try to do my best, in collaboration with the other moderators and community members! Feel free to ping me in [our main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity) and I will try to answer as soon as possible. Hopefully, our community will continue to grow in quantity but especially in quality!

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to our new moderator, Dennis! He has a very good overall knowledge of the AI field, he's patient, and he's been around for a long time, which shows that he cares about this community. I think he will be a good moderator (if he remains at least as active as he has been)!